# Problem Using Stripe Payment In React Native App

Tags: asp.net, react-native, stripe-payments

I am using stripe in React Native App not expo and using .Net Core web api as a backend,
this is my backend code where, stripe customers creates and their ephemeral keys and setup_intent

```
public Customer create_customer()
        {
            StripeConfiguration.ApiKey =_appSettings.StripeApiSecret;
            var options = new CustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Description = "My First Test Customer",
            };
            var service = new CustomerService();
            return service.Create(options);

        }


        public EphemeralKey create_empherical_key(string customerId)
        {
            
            var options = new EphemeralKeyCreateOptions
            {
                StripeVersion = "2020-08-27",
                Customer = customerId
            };
            var service = new EphemeralKeyService();
            return service.Create(options);


        }

        public SetupIntent setup_intent(string customerId)
        {
            var options = new SetupIntentCreateOptions
            {
                Customer = customerId
            };
            var service = new SetupIntentService();
            return service.Create(options);

        }
```

my backend is working fine it creates all the values that stripe needs,

main problem is lying here in React Native app

```
function CheckoutScreen() {
  const { initPaymentSheet, presentPaymentSheet } = useStripe();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const fetchPaymentSheetParams = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${ environment.stripeurl  +`create_customer`}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const { setupIntent, ephemeralKey, customer } = await response.json();
    return {
      setupIntent,
      ephemeralKey,
      customer,
    };
  };

  const initializePaymentSheet = async () => {
    
    const {
      setupIntent,
      ephemeralKey,
      customer,
    } = await fetchPaymentSheetParams();

    const { error } = await initPaymentSheet({
    
      customerId: customer.id,
      customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephemeralKey.secret,
      setupIntentClientSecret: setupIntent.clientSecret,
    });
    if (!error) {
      setLoading(true);
    }
  };

 
    const openPaymentSheet = async () => {
      const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet();
  
      if (error) {
        Alert.alert(`Error code: ${error.code}`, error.message);
      } else {
        Alert.alert('Success', 'Your payment method is successfully set up for future payments!');
      }
  
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    initializePaymentSheet();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        disabled={!loading}
        title="Set up"
        onPress={openPaymentSheet}
      />
      
      </View>
   
  );
```

I receiving all the values of customer, setupintent and ephemeralkey in the front end, when it reach on the line

```
const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet();
```

the app crashes.

for refrence I am also providing link of the documentation.
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet

And these are the packages version that I am currently using in this react-native app.

```
{
  "name": "Tookan_App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.12.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.18.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "^28.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.71.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think we'll need more information about the context & error to help with this. Which platform(s) does this happen on? Are they any specific errors in your app dev logs you can share? What version of the library are you using? Two possible issues are trying to open this from within a modal, or if using Expo the init/present calls for payment sheet might require a different set of params. Ideally, putting together a minimal reproduction and filing an issue with Stripe's repository would allow them to investigate: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/new/choose

Comment: sorry, for the versions, now you can check the versions of the dependencies, and this project is on react-native not on expo, and I debug this app, no error found when it reach the  ```  const { error } = await presentPaymentSheet(); ``` it crashes the app.